# SQL Server Coalesce condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have this piece of code which I am not sure how would it work:

```
UPDATE Data
    SET Processed = 1
FROM Data
JOIN Meters
    ON Meters.ServiceAccount = serv_acct
where COALESCE(Processed, 0) = 0
```

My question is about the last line! Would that line ever be true in this case?
Since I am setting Processed to 1 then how would that work:
`where COALESCE(Processed, 0) = 0`?

Can anybody explain the logic of using Coalesce in this way?

This code is not written by me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your query is:

```
UPDATE Data
    SET Processed = 1
    FROM Data JOIN
         Meters
         ON Meters.ServiceAccount = serv_acct
    where COALESCE(Processed, 0) = 0;
```

An `update` query determines the population of rows it is acting on *before* any of the changes are made.  So, the final line is taking rows where `Processed` is either `NULL` or `0`.  The `update` is then setting `Processed` to `1` for those rows.  In other words, the `where` clause is acting as a filter on the rows to modify.  The specific statement is to keep the rows where the value of `Processed` is `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: What would happen if I have this: where COALESCE(1, 0) = 0; Would this even do the join? As the condition does not match.

Comment: @HotlansyHttlandy . . . `coalesce()` returns the value of the first non-NULL value in the argument list.  So, `coalesce(1, 0) = 0` is always false.  In the context of a join, no rows would match.

Answer (score 0):

The `COALESCE` function is described here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

I think the reason behind using this predicate `where COALESCE(Processed, 0) = 0` was to filter all rows which have column `Processed` IS NULL or equal to 0.

Instead, I would use use predicates:

```
UPDATE Data
SET Processed = 1
FROM Data JOIN
    Meters 
    ON Meters.ServiceAccount = serv_acct
where Processed IS NULL OR Processed = 0;
```

because they are SARGable. This means `Index Seek`.

Applying an expression on `Processed` column will force SQL Server to choose an `[Clustered] Index Scan`.